# Merging different conditional select queries into one - with structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query in SQL Server 2008 as below:

```
;with PassiveCases
AS
(  
  Select t1.id, COUNT(*) as PassiveCounts
  from #Table1 t1
  inner join Table2 t2 on t2.Id = t1.SurgicalRequest_Id 
  inner join Table3 t3 on t3.Id = t2.ReportingIndicator_Id
  inner join Table3 t4 on t4.Id = t3.Id 
  where t4.Passive = 1              
),
ActiveCases
AS
(
  Select t1.id, COUNT(*) as ActiveCounts
  from #Table1 t1
  inner join Table2 t2 on t2.Id = t1.SurgicalRequest_Id 
  inner join Table3 t3 on t3.Id = t2.ReportingIndicator_Id
  inner join Table3 t4 on t4.Id = t3.Id 
  where t4.Passive = 0  
)
```

What I want it to combine these structures into one to increase the efficiency and provide more readability. I am looking for something like below (it doesn't work)

```
:With Cases
AS
(
  Select t1.id, case when t4.Passive = 1 then COUNT(*) as PassiveCounts else COUNT(*) as ActiveCounts
  from #Table1 t1
  inner join Table2 t2 on t2.Id = t1.SurgicalRequest_Id 
  inner join Table3 t3 on t3.Id = t2.ReportingIndicator_Id
  inner join Table3 t4 on t4.Id = t3.Id 
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation.

```
Select t1.id 
,sum(case when t4.Passive = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as PassiveCounts 
,sum(case when t4.Passive <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ActiveCounts
from #Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t2.Id = t1.SurgicalRequest_Id 
inner join Table3 t3 on t3.Id = t2.ReportingIndicator_Id
inner join Table3 t4 on t4.Id = t3.Id 
group by t1.id
```

Answer (score 2):

You just want conditional aggregation.  In your case, though, you can do this with arithmetic:

```
With Cases AS (
      Select t1.id, sum(t4.Passive) as PassiveCount, sum(1 - t4.Passive) as ActiveCount
      from #Table1 t1 inner join
           Table2 t2
           on t2.Id = t1.SurgicalRequest_Id inner join
           Table3 t3
           on t3.Id = t2.ReportingIndicator_Id inner join
           Table3 t4
           on t4.Id = t3.Id 
     group by t1.id
    )
```

According to your question, `t4.Passive` only takes on two values, so the arithmetic should do what you want.

Comment: need GROUP BY clause